# Shelter {about | of} me?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

From *Where I Lived, and What I Lived For* by Henry David Thoreau:

> The only house I had been the owner of before, if I except a boat, was a tent, which I used occasionally when making excursions in the summer, and this is still rolled up in my garret; but the boat, after passing from hand to hand, has gone down the stream of time. With **this more substantial shelter about me**, I had made some progress toward settling in the world. [Emphasis added.]

How can a shelter be *about* him? I think it should be *of mine.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*About,* in this sense, means

> prep.
>   1. On all sides of; surrounding: *I found an English garden all about me.*

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=About)

So his new shelter is around him, protecting him. The shelter is also "of his" (belonging to him), as is made clear in text preceding this excerpt.

Comment: Note that this usage is less common in modern parlance, though not completely antiquated yet.  It might seem a bit too "poetic" to use in everyday speech.